# How to catch a rejected promise and continue a promise change with kovenant

Tags: kotlin, kovenant

With kovenant, if i have a promise chain, sometimes i want to continue that chain for certain errors.

In javascript you can return a new promise in .catch() but with kovenant, you can't return a new promise in the .fail().

So i was wondering how one should do this with kovenant.